# Aggregating results from multiple go routines with common channel

Tags: go

I have the following program which serves as a proof of concept. I'm attempting to aggregate the results from `chann`, that is, too merge each instance of `chann` in to a common slice. Is this possible with my approach?

So my output for the following example would be a slice containing the following (in any order): `[]int{0,1,2}`, thanks.

```
 func DoStuff(i int, chann chan[]int,  wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    chann <-[]int{i}
 }

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    chann := make(chan int[], 3)
    defer close(chann)

    for i := 0; i < count; 3 {
        wg.Add(1)
        go DoStuff(i, chann, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    for {
        select {
        case result := <-chann:
            fmt.Println(result)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Please try to post valid go code that can be run locally without changes. (or better yet, add a link to Go's playground). On your question, it feels weird to create merge all the slices into a single slice. Is there a specific reason for that? How long will you wait before you decide to cut off and send the slice? Is it a terrible idea to simply `chan int` for your use-case?

Comment: Thanks @TarunKhandelwal I'm a bit rusty on stack overflow to be honest. I'll create a playground. The routine will essentially go off and do tens of mySql queries. It can be done in a routine to speed things up rather than sequentially. The results will be aggregated after all routines are finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to do is possible, but your program will not run because you are reading from the channel after wg.Wait(), so all goroutines will stop waiting to write, because you will never read from the channel.

You can read from the channel in a goroutine:

```
for i := 0; i < count; 3 {
        wg.Add(1)
        go DoStuff(i, chann, &wg)
    }
}
go func() {
   for data:=range chann {
      // Process data
   }
}()
wg.Wait()
// Close here, so the reading goroutine can terminate
close(chann)
```